# Mysql get latest record on multiple rows by user by datetime or unixtime

Tags: mysql, group-by

I tried to search on stackoverflow, google. I mostly see that we use max. But, on my records, it will be a thousand rows, so it would eat so much time before it get's finished.

Basically, I just want to get the latest record by datetime or unixtime.

The table records, sorted by datetime ASC:

> Query: select * from accounts order by datetime ASC;

```
+----------+--------+---------------------+------------+
| user_id  | status | datetime            | unixtime   |
+----------+--------+---------------------+------------+
| 14254047 |      1 | 2013-03-27 01:25:12 | 1364343912 | 
| 14254270 |      1 | 2013-03-27 09:36:58 | 1364373418 | 
| 14254619 |      1 | 2013-03-27 16:07:04 | 1364396824 | 
| 14254047 |      0 | 2013-05-08 07:20:39 | 1367990439 | 
| 14254270 |      0 | 2013-05-09 04:01:36 | 1368064896 | 
| 14254619 |      0 | 2013-05-09 04:01:36 | 1368064896 | 
+----------+--------+---------------------+------------+
```

When I grouped them by user_id, the result always show the first record. Not the latest, even adding order by datetime or unixtime DESC

> Query: select * from accounts group by user_id order by datetime DESC;

```
+----------+--------+---------------------+------------+
| user_id  | status | datetime            | unixtime   |
+----------+--------+---------------------+------------+
| 14254047 |      1 | 2013-03-27 01:25:12 | 1364343912 | 
| 14254270 |      1 | 2013-03-27 09:36:58 | 1364373418 | 
| 14254619 |      1 | 2013-03-27 16:07:04 | 1364396824 | 
+----------+--------+---------------------+------------+
```

The result I wanted are the following:

```
+----------+--------+---------------------+------------+
| user_id  | status | datetime            | unixtime   |
+----------+--------+---------------------+------------+
| 14254047 |      0 | 2013-05-08 07:20:39 | 1367990439 | 
| 14254270 |      0 | 2013-05-09 04:01:36 | 1368064896 | 
| 14254619 |      0 | 2013-05-09 04:01:36 | 1368064896 | 
+----------+--------+---------------------+------------+
```

What could be the best approach, without using MAX()?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Like in most auto-increment situations the `max(ID)` is actually a better indicator of the most recent record then `max(datetime)` is.   The reason for this is that the unique auto-increment is a tie-breaker on records with the same time.

Even better is that many out there probably already have an index on the auto-increment column so use this if you can.

The caveats are:

1. you like accuracy and care about data quality
2. that you care about the relative time the item was created. If a modification to datetime is possible and desired then you use datetime column.
3. That you have an auto-increment column (like ID described above) in your accounts table.  The select * says you do not so that's too bad. But you could add one!

the query. I called the `ID` column above `accounts.id` in this query:

```
select a.*
from accounts a join
    (select user_id, max(id) as maxid
     from accounts
     group by user_id
    ) asum
  on asum.user_id = a.user_id and a.id = asum.maxid
order by a.id DESC;
```

Comment: The reason why datetime is part of my criteria is, there are some late/future records that where modified, making the ids as invalid.

Comment: That's fine maybe this will help someone else who can use an ID.  FYI the `select *` in the question implies there is no `ID` on accounts yet.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is using a join:

```
select a.*
from accounts a join
     (select user_id, max(datetime) as maxdt
      from accounts
      group by user_id
     ) asum
     on asum.user_id = a.user_id and a.datetime = asum.maxdt
order by datetime DESC;
```

Your original query uses an extension in MySQL where you can have columns in the `select` clause that are not in the `group by` clause (or in aggregation functions).  When you do this, MySQL is explicit that the values are *not* determinate.  They may sometimes come from the first row, but this behavior is not guaranteed.

Comment: Should max always be used? It takes time for it to finish on a thousand of rows.

Comment: @LouieMiranda . . . There might be other alternative formulations using `exists`, but it would be the same idea.  A thousand rows is not very many rows, so performance should not be much of an issue, unless you are running this query many times per second.

Answer (score 0):

I was stucked in the same problem and I got my solution on the solution provided by [Oliver Hanappi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491329/group-by-with-maxdate)