# How to get the row that holds the last value in a queue of identical values? (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I think it's easier to show you an image:

[image]

So, for each *fld_call_id*, go to the next value, if it's identical. When we get to the last value, I need the value in column *fld_menu_id*.

Or, to put it in another way, eliminate *fld_call_id* duplicates and save only the last one.

Comment: The last one is a very vague concept, as it depends on the order of rows. Do you need the one with the highest fld_menu_id?

Comment: The image might be helpful, but you should also post the sample data as text, so that we can copy/paste it.

Comment: Anyway... this looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491329/group-by-with-maxdate

Comment: @Frazz The one with the highest fld_id actually.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS( 
    SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fld_call_id ORDER BY fld_id DESC),
           fld_menu_id
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT fld_menu_id FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Rank column and only select that row, something along the lines of the following:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT
  *
  ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY fld_call_id ORDER BY fld_id DESC) Rnk
 FROM YourTable
)
SELECT
 *
FROM cte
WHERE Rnk=1
```

So you `GROUP BY fld_call_id` and `ORDER BY fld_id` in `descending` order so that the last value comes first. These are the rows where `Rnk=1`.

Edit after comments of OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table.*
FROM Table
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(fldMenuID) AS fldMenuID,
    fldCallID
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY fldCallID
) maxValues
ON (maxValues.fldMenuID = Table.fldMenuID
AND maxValues.fldCallID= Table.fldCallID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope This works

```
SELECT  A.*
FROM    table A
JOIN    (SELECT fld_id,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Fld_call_id ORDER BY fld_id DESC) [Row]
        FROM    table) LU ON A.fld_id = LU.fld_id
WHERE   LU.[Row] = 1
```