# select row with max value of a group of rows in sql

Tags: mysql, groupwise-maximum

I have a table "products" that has the columns "name" and price". There are multiple prices for the same name. The table looks like

```
shampoo 7
shampoo 10
shampoo 8
bread   1
bread   1.5
water   0.5
water   0.7
......
```

I want the row with the max price. I tried

```
select name, price
from products
group by name
having max(price);
```

Note: My problem isn't that, but I wanna know the logic behind the solution. Thanks.

Comment: could you see .
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491329/group-by-with-maxdate

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Comment: Do you want the maximum price overall or for each product? (First select max(price) from products, second: select name, max(price) from products group by name). For the first case you would get the row with the maximum by select * from products where price=(select max(price) from products)

Answer (score 3):

Create one group or rows for each distinct name using `group by name`.  You can then select the `name` (because every row in the group has the same name.)  The group has many prices, and you can use the aggregate function `max()` to retrieve the highest price for the group.

```
select  name
,       max(price) as MaxPrice
from    Products
group by
        name
```

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive answer.