# How to find last update in my table based on date and time

Tags: sql

I have table like below

```
|   time         | ename  | cid    | userid  |  day
-------------------------------------------------------
|  1455865003573 | fol    |  11228 | 107757  |20160218
|  1455865000083 | unfol  |  11228 | 107757  |20160218
|  1455874888381 | unfol  |  11229 | 107757  |20160219
|  1455874892944 | fol    |  11229 | 107757  |20160219
```

I want output like below based on last max(time) on each cid,userid,day.

```
|   time         | ename  | cid    | userid  |  day
-------------------------------------------------------
|  1455865003573 | fol    |  11228 | 107757  |20160218
|  1455874892944 | fol    |  11229 | 107757  |20160219
```

Please help me on this.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You need to decide which DBMS you are using instead of tagging all of them.

Comment: Have you tried anything or do you want us to do it for you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491329/group-by-with-maxdate

Comment: Hi all, I am using sql ,i have tried group By functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1
```

This would give you the row with the highest time.

or to get the same as what u said you wanted:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ename='fol' ORDER BY time DESC
```

Comment: Hi Firewizz,i have so much of data(rows of data ) in the same date. so i should not use   WHERE ename='fol') and desc. because ename may be fol/unfol depends on the Max(Time)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server than this query is worked for you.

```
select * from (select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [cid],[userid],[day] 
order by [time] desc) RowNum,* from yourtablename)T where RowNum=1
```