# MySQL - Return Last Record For Each Data Group

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Using the following data...

```
+--------------+--------+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
| EQUIPMENT_ID | CML_ID | INSPECTION_NO | INSPECTION_DATE | WALL_THICKNESS |
+--------------+--------+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
| B1000-V001   | 1      | 1             | 1/01/2016       | 10             |
| B1000-V001   | 1      | 2             | 2/01/2016       | 9              |
| B1000-V001   | 1      | 3             | 3/01/2016       | 3              |
| B1000-V001   | 1      | 4             | 4/01/2016       | 7              |
| B1000-V001   | 1      | 5             | 5/01/2016       | 5              |
| B1000-V001   | 1      | 6             | 6/01/2016       | 4              |
| B1000-V001   | 1      | 7             | 7/01/2016       | 4              |
| B1000-V001   | 1      | 8             | 8/01/2016       | 8              |
| B1000-V001   | 1      | 9             | 9/01/2016       | 17             |
| B1000-V001   | 1      | 10            | 10/01/2016      | 5              |
| B1000-X123   | 5      | 1             | 1/01/2016       | 2              |
| B1000-X123   | 5      | 2             | 2/01/2016       | 8              |
| B1000-X123   | 5      | 3             | 3/01/2016       | 4              |
| B1000-X123   | 5      | 4             | 4/01/2016       | 5              |
| B1000-X123   | 5      | 5             | 5/01/2016       | 7              |
| B1000-P789   | 3      | 1             | 1/01/2016       | 8              |
| B1000-P789   | 3      | 2             | 2/01/2016       | 7              |
| B1000-P789   | 3      | 3             | 3/01/2016       | 5              |
| B1000-P789   | 3      | 4             | 4/01/2016       | 1              |
| B1000-P789   | 3      | 5             | 5/01/2016       | 4              |
+--------------+--------+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
```

I want the fastest way to produce the following result...

```
+--------------+--------+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
| EQUIPMENT_ID | CML_ID | INSPECTION_NO | INSPECTION_DATE | WALL_THICKNESS |
| B1000-V001   | 1      | 10            | 10/01/2016      | 5              |
| B1000-P789   | 3      | 5             | 5/01/2016       | 4              |
| B1000-X123   | 5      | 5             | 5/01/2016       | 7              |
+--------------+--------+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
```

i.e. GROUP BY EQUIPMENT_ID, CML_ID and always return the record associated to the maximum inspection number.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491329/group-by-with-maxdate?noredirect=1&lq=1  This is what you need.

Comment: @Ashok Great thanks. There are a lot of good solutions to this problem here.

Comment: Somds like a [_Groupwise max problem_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/groupwise-max-in-mariadb/)

Comment: Thanks Rick. Some more good solutions in this article

Answer (score 0):

Try Below query.

```
    Select a.Equipment_ID, a.CML_ID, b.INSPECTION_NO,a.INSPECTION_DATE, a.WALL_THICKNESS
    from
    #YourTable a inner join
    (
    Select Equipment_ID, CML_ID, max(INSPECTION_NO)as INSPECTION_NO
    from #YourTable
    Group By Equipment_ID,CML_ID 
    ) b
    on a.Equipment_ID=b.Equipment_ID and a.CML_ID=b.CML_ID and a.INSPECTION_NO=b.INSPECTION_NO
    order by a.Equipment_ID
```

SQL_FIDDLE  :  [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9b38d/22)

Please let us know if you have any questions or concerns.

Comment: thanks for the response but strawberry and ashok have already provided a response.