# Qlikview TOTAL Aggr Combined Logic

Tags: qlikview

I have a grid chart with the fields below in it.  What I'm seeing is that the Example2 field has a single value for all rows, and that value is larger than the largest Example1 value from any of the rows.  What I would expect is that Example2 would be equal to the largest value from Example1.  Is that correct?  Does anyone understand why I'm getting this value for Example2?  I've also provided example output data below.

```
Example1:

Max({<Field1=>} Aggr(Sum({<Field2={'Value'}, Field1=>} StuffCount), Field1))


Example2:

Max({<Field1=>} TOTAL Aggr(Sum({<Field2={'Value'}, Field1=>} StuffCount), Field1))


Example Output:

Field1 Example1 Example2
tod      1        4
bob      0        4
eric     2        4
```

Comment: First of all, Example 1 calc doesn't make sense, why just not use max({<field2={value}>} stuffCount) and then for example 2 use Max({<Field1=>} TOTAL Aggr(Max({<Field2={'Value'}, Field1=>} StuffCount), Field1))

Comment: I recommend you reading this example which explains the difference between AGGR and TOTAL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446403/total-vs-aggr-in-qlikview/44844476#44844476