# Way to find the maximum dates with no futuristic dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm trying to list the latest Quantity (MAX EffectiveDate time avoiding Futuristic EffectiveDate) for each Code in a table

```
Code     Quantity EffectiveDate
1        2        1-Mar-2018
1        3        1-Apr-2018
1        3        1-May-2018
1        3        1-June-2018
2        5        1-Mar-2018
2        6        1-Apr-2018
3        7        1-Feb-2018
3        8        1-Mar-2018
3        5        1-Apr-2018
```

The Desired output should be:

```
Code     Quantity EffectiveDate
1        3        1-May-2018
2        6        1-Apr-2018
3        5        1-Apr-2018
```

I tried the solution from 
[GROUP BY with MAX(DATE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491329/group-by-with-maxdate)
But it is showing futuristic data.

Comment: Use WHERE to avoid the future!

Comment: Or `HAVING`, depends on what your goal is here.

Comment: What is the datatype of EffectiveDate?

Comment: @jarlh are you saying there is a place WHERE is no future?

Comment: @Larnu it sure looks like is a probability based on the sample data posted. Which would certainly explain why MAX isn't doing what they want.

Comment: @SeanLange Possibly. I do wonder though, as if they are storing it as a `varchar` though. If they were, that means that all the dates they have stored are on the first of the month. With `varchar` dates in the format `dd-MMM-yyyy` format, `MAX` is most likely going to be bringing back dates with the day having a value of `30` or `31`.

Comment: I figure it must be varchar because not all the months in the sample data have 2 characters. June has four where all the other are 3. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get full rows you could use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM table
WHERE EffectiveDate <= GETDATE()
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY code ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6daca91277545977e8d9b15e56e71cd4)**

---

**EDIT:**

If among one code group ties are possible, then you could use `RANK`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM tab
WHERE EffectiveDate <= GETDATE()
ORDER BY RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY code ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c1712a8ee372a7ad99d8e194d6a84b96)**

Comment: I'm a true fan of the combiation of *`TOP 1 WITH TIES` and `ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER()`*. I've used this quite often myself.

Comment: @Shnugo I love it too. Especially when combined with `RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`. Then I get ties in groups(PARTITION BY) and for all groups. **[Demo with RANK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c1712a8ee372a7ad99d8e194d6a84b96)**

Answer (score 4):

It depends what your goal is here. If you want to ignore if the `MAX` date is in the future, you need to use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT Code,
       Quantity,
       MAX(EffectiveDate)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Code, Quantity
HAVING MAX(EffectiveDate) <= GETDATE();
```

If, however, you want the `MAX` date which is less than the current date, use a `WHERE`:

```
SELECT Code,
       Quantity,
       MAX(EffectiveDate)
FROM YourTable
WHERE EffectiveDate <= GETDATE()
GROUP BY Code, Quantity;
```

Your question is unclear on which answer is correct; and we can't infer from any sample data.

Edit:

If we use the following Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable (Code int, Quantity int, EffectiveDate date);
GO

INSERT INTO YourTable
VALUES(1,1,'20180501'),
      (1,1,'20180516'),
      (1,1,'20180521'),
      (2,1,'20180501'),
      (2,1,'20180521'),
      (3,1,'20180501');
GO
```

For the first query, the result would be:

```
Code        Quantity    EffectiveDate
----------- ----------- -------------
3           1           2018-05-01
```

For the second, it would be:

```
Code        Quantity    EffectiveDate
----------- ----------- -------------
1           1           2018-05-16
2           1           2018-05-01
3           1           2018-05-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `WHERE` clause with `GETDATE()` function

```
where data < getdate()
```