# Selecting the first record out of each nested grouped record

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I've built a query (in Oracle) that selects any row with the max date out of duplicated rows. I based my query on the one presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3491386/3002584), which uses a nested grouping:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT Train, MAX(Time) as MaxTime
      FROM TrainTable
      GROUP BY Train
) r
INNER JOIN TrainTable t
ON t.Train = r.Train AND t.Time = r.MaxTime
```

Now, since that query doesn't account for duplicated values in `Time` (as commented [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491329/group-by-with-maxdate#comment48041022_3491386)), I'd like to take the **first** record out of each "duplicated" grouped record, *and to still be able to use `select *`*.

How can I do it?

(P.S. I tried using the other solution (using `over (partition ...)`), but it didn't work, and I'd need to figure it out)

Comment: So basically, you want to be able to use "SELECT * FROM " and also a Group By clause? Honestly, even if you get a satisfactory answer it will be inferior to learning and understanding what "the other solution" does with a partition. It's more complicated to understand but well worth your time.

Comment: @BarryPiccinni, I'm certainly going to do that, but also want to know how to use this kind of query :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by train order by time desc) as seqnum
      from traintable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This returns an *arbitrary* row when there are ties for the matching `time`.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no "first" row, unless another column specifies that ordering.  If so, then you can include that column in the `order by` clause.

Comment: It seems there's no easy-enough *and* performant way to do it without using `partition`, so although this answer doesn't use the original query, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `PK` in table (`TrainTable`) then you can use `fetch first` clause with `subquery` :

```
select t.*
from traintable t
where t.pk = (select t1.pk
              from traintable t1
              where t1.train = t.train 
              order by t1.time desc
              fetch first 1 rows only
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way you can make it without *window function*

You can try to use a subquery in `select`, to get `COUNT` be row_number and set the `partition by` columns in subquery `where` clause.

```
CREATE TABLE TrainTable(
    train varchar(10),
    Time  date
);
INSERT INTO TrainTable values ('A',to_date('2017-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO TrainTable values ('A',to_date('2018-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO TrainTable values ('B',to_date('2017-05-01','YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO TrainTable values ('B',to_date('2017-05-05','YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO TrainTable values ('C',to_date('2017-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT t.*,(SELECT 
                COUNT(*) FROM TrainTable t1 
                WHERE t1.Time >= t.Time AND 
                      t1.train = t.train
               ) rn
    FROM TrainTable t
    ORDER BY t.Time DESC
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e54660/6/0)**:

```
| TRAIN |                 TIME | RN |
|-------|----------------------|----|
|     A | 2018-01-01T00:00:00Z |  1 |
|     B | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z |  1 |
|     C | 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z |  1 |
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist in using this example in your answer, you could lump your current query into a WITH block and then SELECT DISTINCT like so:

```
WITH query AS (
  SELECT r.*
  FROM (
    SELECT train, MAX(trainTime) as MaxTime
    FROM trainTimes
    GROUP BY train
  ) r
  INNER JOIN trainTimes t
  ON t.train = r.train AND t.trainTime = r.MaxTime
)
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM query;
```

Here is a SQL fiddle of this working: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a290e/29)

**HOWEVER**

This is inefficient, and whilst it works for the current example it will probably get messy in a real DB. If Gordon's answer gives you the desired output, it's a far better solution.