# Java - filter list of objects by property combo and most recent date

Tags: java, list, filter, compare, java-stream

I have a list of objects with the properties name, company, and date. I want to filter that list to get the most recent name+company combo based on the date. Example data:

```
id | name | company | date
----------------------
 1 | bob  |    A    | 01/2017
 2 | bob  |    A    | 01/2016
 3 | bob  |    A    | 01/2015
 4 | bob  |    B    | 03/2017
 5 | sal  |    B    | 04/2018
 6 | sue  |    A    | 01/2016
 7 | sue  |    A    | 01/2017
 8 | sue  |    A    | 01/2015
```

The desired result should be a list containing ids: 1, 4, 5, and 7.

I could go through each item on my list and add it to a new list if the name + company combo doesn't exist, and if it does, check the date to see if the existing one should be replaced. But I feel there should be an easier way to do this through streams and filters. I just can't think of how. Searching provides methods such as Collections.max, but I want a list of the max based on a combo.

These are java constructed objects, not persisted entities, otherwise I'd do something like this: [GROUP BY with MAX(DATE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491329/group-by-with-maxdate). But I want to accomplish the same thing.

Is it possible to do this using a filter or is my only option the long route?

Comment: I would suggest you drop the `Stream` idea and look for a better DB retrieve approach.

Comment: These are java-constructed objects, not entities, otherwise I would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the groupingBy method from the Collectors API. It allows you to provide a fuction that creates a key based on an object from your stream and then gets you a Map>. You would get a code like:

```
Function<YourObject, String> keyGen = o -> o.getName() + o.getCompany();
Comparator<YourObject> comp = (f1, f2) -> f1.date().compareTo(f2.getDate()
yourObjects.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(keyGen)).values().stream().map(list -> Collections.max(list, comp)).map(MyObject::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same problem here. Here's the solution I got with a database expert friend:

```
SELECT 
    b1.name,b1.date, b1.balance, b1.user_id
FROM table_name b1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT b.name,max(b.date) as maxdate,b.user_id
                FROM table_name b
               GROUP BY b.user_id,b.name, CAST(b.date as date)) as b2 ON b2.user_id = b1.user_id AND b2.name = b1.name AND b2.maxdate = b1.date
where b1.user_id = '1'
and b1.date >= '2021-11-01 00:00:00'
AND b1.date <= '2021-11-30 23:59:59'
order by b1.name, b1."date" asc ;
```