# Sqlite date time, getting the latest date

Tags: sqlite, date

I have a project about a clinic. I have a table in my database that is about the consultation of the patients. My field's are patientid and consultaion_date. So the example inputs is like this:

```
PatientID|consultation_date
1        |  January/3/2001
1        |  December/2/2001
1        |  December/6/2003
1        |  January/2/2005
2        |  January/3/2005
2        |  January/31/2005
2        |  April/5/2005
```

Can I have a query statement that's going to give me the patientID and the latest date of the consultation of the patients?

```
 PatientID|consultation_date
 1        |  January/2/2005
 2        |  April/5/2005
```

Comment: Have you see similar answer like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491329/group-by-with-maxdate

Comment: Are you literally representing dates in the database with strings in the format shown in the question?

Comment: Not with that date format, no, since, say, December sorts before June.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that.
I'll change my format