# Retrieve latest date oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is a sample of the Table

```
id   from        to         value
1    01.01.20    19.01.20   100
1    20.01.20    31.12.99   100
2    01.01.20    19.01.20   1001
2    25.01.20    31.12.99   1001
3    01.01.20    19.01.20   1002
3    29.01.20    31.12.99   1002
```

The aim is to retrieve the latest row

The expected output should look like this

```
id   from        to         value
1    20.01.20    31.12.99   100
2    25.01.20    31.12.99   1001
3    29.01.20    31.12.99   1002
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
select *
from test
where id in a
AND from = (select max(from) 
   from test 
   where id in a);
```

However, I am retrieving only one row

```
3    29.01.20    31.12.99   1002
```

Thanks for anyone helping!

Comment: Please explain the logic.  It is not clear.

Comment: You will need to use `group by`

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3491386/259889

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need simple aggregation using `MAX` and `GROUP BY`:

```
with t as
(
    select 1 id, '01.01.20' "from", '19.01.20' "to", 100 "value" from dual union all
    select 1, '20.01.20', '31.12.99', 100 from dual union all
    select 2, '01.01.20', '19.01.20', 1001 from dual union all
    select 2, '25.01.20', '31.12.99', 1001 from dual union all
    select 3, '01.01.20', '19.01.20', 1002 from dual union all
    select 3, '29.01.20', '31.12.99', 1002 from dual
)
select id, max("from"), max("to"), "value" from t
group by id, "value"
order by id;

        ID from     to            value
---------- -------- -------- ----------
         1 20.01.20 31.12.99        100
         2 25.01.20 31.12.99       1001
         3 29.01.20 31.12.99       1002
```

On a side note, `'01.01.20'` is a string and not a date. So, please make sure you use appropriate `DATE` data type for date values.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the latest row per ID -

```
SELECT 
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id, from DESC) RN
      FROM test)
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

You seem to want:

```
select t.*
from test t
where t.to_date = '31.12.99'
```

Comment: That assumes that the max date will always be '31-12-99'.

Comment: This was a sample, the date isn't always 31.12.99

Comment: @Si . . . I can only respond to the question that was asked.  That is true of all the sample data in the question.