# How to find Minimum semester in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, greatest-n-per-group

I want to select starting semester of the student.

```
select distinct (stdcode),altcode,name,admdate,sem_code
,min(startsem)
from V_ALLSTUDATAAA
GROUP BY stdcode,altcode,name,degree_code,sem_code
order by altcode;
```

Desired Results:

[image]

Sample Data is attached below.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-oqXgGfhIiLwWKLpUx94P9n1hXUAUE3dn3jAPV8HQ_k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your query seems working fine to get desired results. Just include ADMDATE in GROUP BY statement.

Comment: but i want to find first semester system show all semester of all minimum date.

Comment: Its a bit hard to digest what you really want here - because it looks like every student started on 08-sep-08.  Also, the best way to get support is to give the data in such a way that its easy for people to replicate it on their own system. So you should give us the "create table" statement and then an "insert" statement for each row.

Comment: Please check new updated sample data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column). Or this: [GROUP BY with MAX(DATE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491329/group-by-with-maxdate)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a correlated subquery; something like this:

```
select a.stdcode, a.altcode, a.name, a.admdate, a.degree_code, a.sem_code, a.startsem
from v_allstudataaa a
where a.startsem = (select min(b.startsem)
                    from v_allstudataaa b
                    where b.stdcode = a.stdcode
                   );
```