# How to select distinct based on condition (another column)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select distinct values from a table based on `date` column. I mean I want to extract the distinct rows with higher value of `date` column

```
ID| house | people| date
------------------------------
1 |   a   |   5   | 2021-10-20
2 |   a   |   5   | 2022-01-20
3 |   b   |   4   | 2021-10-20
4 |   b   |   4   | 2022-01-20
```

After query is runned, I want the below result:

```
   a   |   5   | 2022-01-20
   b   |   4   | 2022-01-20
```

I have tried below query but I have no idea how to add the condition (show the distinct row with higher date value.
`SELECT DISTINCT house, people FROM Table`

I tried `SELECT DISTINCT house, people FROM Table WHERE MAX(date)`  but got some errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can use group by, very similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491329/group-by-with-maxdate

Comment: Forget distinct. Try `WHERE MAX(date) = date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the row number for each row partitoned by `house` and ordered by `date desc`. then only select the rows with row number = 1:

```
select house, people, date
from(select house, people, date, row_number() over(partition by house order by date desc) rn
from table_name) t
where rn = 1
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9c0923a9a52229f35c531a428e55d43c)

Comment: @PaulViorel what if a (house, people) record does not have a new date? This solution does not seem to cope with that scenario. Or can we exclude that possibility?

Comment: @LajosArpad I need that record, it keeps the date when that row is inserted into DataBase.

Answer (score 0):

You will need aggregation via `group by` and the `max` `date`, filtering out rows that are older to 1) ensure that your grouping occurs faster and 2) ignore items that have no newer date values.

```
SELECT house, people, max(`date`)
FROM Table
WHERE `date` > '2021-10-20 00:00:00'
GROUP BY house, people
```