# Using SQL, how do I select which column to add a value to, based on the contents of the row?

Tags: sql

I'm having a difficult time phrasing the question, so I think the best thing to do is to give some example tables. I have a table, Attribute_history, I'm trying to pull data from that looks like this:

```
ID   Attribute_Name  Attribute_Val  Time Stamp
---  --------------  -------------  ----------
1    Color           Red            2022/09/28 01:00
2    Color           Blue           2022/09/28 01:30
1    Length          3              2022/09/28 01:00
2    Length          4              2022/09/28 01:30
1    Diameter        5              2022/09/28 01:00
2    Diameter        10             2022/09/28 01:30
2    Diameter        11             2022/09/28 01:32
```

I want to create a table that pulls the attributes of each ID, and if the same ID and attribute_name has been updated, pull the latest info based on Time Stamp.

```
ID    Color   Length  Diameter
----  ------  ------- -------- 
1     Red     3       5 
2     Blue    4       11
```

I've achieved this by nesting several select statements, adding one column at a time. I achieved selecting the latest date using [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491329/group-by-with-maxdate). However, this code seems inefficient, since I'm selecting from the same table multiple times. It also only chooses the latest value for an attribute I know is likely to have been updated multiple times, not all the values I'm interested in.

```
SELECT
    COLOR, DIAMETER, DATE_
FROM
(
    SELECT
        COLORS.COLOR, ATTR.ATTRIBUTE_NAME AS DIAMETER, ATTR.TIME_STAMP AS DATE_, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY COLORS.COLOR ORDER BY ATTR.TIME_STAMP DESC) DATE_RANK -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491329/group-by-with-maxdate
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ATTRIBUTE_HISTORY.ATTRIBUTE_VAL
        FROM
            ATTRIBUTE_HISTORY
        WHERE
            ATTRIBUTE_HISTORY.ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'Color'
        GROUP BY ATTRIBUTE_HISTORY.ID
    ) COLORS
    INNER JOIN ATTRIBUTE_HISTORY ATTR ON COLORS.ID = ATTR.ID
    WHERE
        ATTR.ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'DIAMETER' 
)
WHERE
    DATE_RANK = 1
```

(I copied my real query and renamed values with Find+Replace to obscure the data so this code might not be perfect, but it gets across the idea of how I'm achieving my goal now.)

How can I rewrite this query to be more concise, and pull the latest date entry for each attribute?

Comment: Why do you GROUP BY in the derived table? (I see no aggregate function.)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Is it oracle like in the link you provided?

Comment: @DannySlor db2, I believe.

Comment: @jarlh it's to remove duplicates. The real table has duplicates for some things.

Comment: I see, you're doing `SELECT DISTINCT` in another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For MS SQL Server**

Your Problem has 2 parts:

1. Identify the latest Attribute value based on Time Stamp Column
2. Convert the Attribute Names to columns ( Pivoting ) in the final
   result.

**Solution:**

```
;with CTEx as
(
    select 
    row_number() over(partition by id, Attr_name order by Time_Stamp desc) rnum,
    id,Attr_name, Attr_value, time_stamp
    from #temp
)
SELECT * FROM   
(
    SELECT id,Attr_name,Attr_value
    FROM CTEx 
    where rnum = 1
) t 
PIVOT(
    max(Attr_value) 
    FOR Attr_name IN (Color,Diameter,[Length])
) AS pivot_table;
```

First part of the problem is taken care of by the CTE with the help of `ROW_NUMBER()` function. Second part is achieved by using `PIVOT()` function.

Definition of `#temp` for reference

```
Create table #temp(id int, Attr_name varchar(200), Attr_value varchar(200), Time_Stamp datetime)
```